# OpenGL: Do I still need an array of vertices after buffering to VBO?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vertex-buffer

Let's say that I have an array of vertices and a VBO pointer:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
GLuint vbo;
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
```

Now I buffer the data:

```
glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    vertices.size()*sizeof(Vertex), 
    &vertices[0],
    GL_STATIC_DRAW
);
```

If I understand this correctly I still need to keep vertices array due to `GL_STATIC_DRAW`. However if I change it to `GL_STATIC_COPY` then all of the data will be copied to GPU's memory so I can free memory used by `vertices`. Is that correct? If that's the case why do we need `*_DRAW`? Is that useful because of the GPU's memory limit? Plus how does `GL_STATIC_READ` really work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of this is explained in the `glBufferData()` man pages.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBufferData.xhtml

You don't need to keep an extra copy in your program's memory.  The whole purpose of `glBufferData()` is to copy data from your program to an OpenGL buffer, once the copy is complete, you can do whatever you want with your program memory.

> If data is not NULL, the data store is initialized with data from this pointer.

Do not use `GL_STATIC_COPY`, that is incorrect.  The documentation reads:

> `COPY`
>
> The data store contents are modified by reading data from the GL, and used as the source for GL drawing and image specification commands.

So `GL_STATIC_COPY` is only for internal copies between different OpenGL buffers, not for copies from your application to OpenGL.  Use `DRAW`.